# how to overlap one view on another view in react native android

Tags: react-native

I want to put Search Input between two View border,but half input hides behind another View.

[Click Here To Show Image. 
There are two views. One View's backgroundColor is purple and another view's backgroundColor is white.And half Input type is hide behind another view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REWOu.png)

```
 <Container>
    <Header style={{ backgroundColor: "#635DB7" }}>
      <Left>
        <Button 
          transparent
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}
        >
          <Icon name="ios-menu" />
        </Button>
      </Left>

      <Right />
      </Header>

            <View style={{flex:1,zIndex:2}}>
                <View style={{height:192,backgroundColor: "#635DB7"}}>
                    <View style={{position:'absolute',opacity: 1,flex:1,flexDirection:"row",marginTop:160}}>
                    <Input style={{flexDirection:"row",borderRadius:20,marginLeft:30,marginRight:30,backgroundColor:"#434353", zIndex: 2,opacity: 1}} placeholder="Search" />
                    </View>
                </View>

                <View style={{height:448,backgroundColor: "#ffffff",zIndex:1}}>
                </View>
            </View>



  </Container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the search bar as a last item in the container, and with absolute position. If that does not work, then you might have hit a bug in RN android, which does not support overflow:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6802

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3198

Comment: Thanks sfratini .After puting search bar last in container,its working.